# Problem In Open Or Use master.mdf database in C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio, connection-string

I define `Sql_Cmd` And Other `sql` variable that need before
and Now write this code:

```
string strConnection2 = "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;AttachDbFilename=master.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
SqlConnection sqlcon2 = new SqlConnection(strConnection2);
string sql = "select * ";
Sql_Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
Sql_Cmd.CommandText = sql;
Sql_Cmd.Connection = sqlcon2;
try
{
    sqlcon2.Open();
    Sql_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (SqlException Error_Exception)
{
    //FormError1 = new FormErrorInDataBase();
    //FormError1.Show();
}
```

When I want to open `sqlcon2` I see this error:

> > An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file master.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Please help me - how can I open `master database` and then use select query for this database, and what is the connection string for `master.mdf`?

Can I write the directory of `mater.mdf` such as `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf` or is it enough that I write `AttachDbFilename=master.mdf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your parameters again. The right syntax to add an .mdf-file is as follows. Attach a database file on connect to a local SQL Server Express instance:

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=c:\asd\qwe\mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

Why is the Database parameter needed? If the named database have already been attached, SQL Server does not reattach it. It uses the attached database as the default for the connection.

See: [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008#p1)

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to open 'the' master database?  The system database called 'master' is used internally by SQL Server and should not / does not need to be opened or attached in this way.  If not, you'll have to call your database something other than 'master' - that is a reserved database name.

Comment: and i can't select any thing from this database. and what is the connection string for this database

Comment: What do you mean?  Which database?  The master database is a system reserved database.  You don't need to attach another database to use it.  The connection string is whatever you use to connect to the server, `Initial Catalog=master` if you want it.

Answer (score 1):

master database is the system database that contains system information about SQL Server instance, information about databases contained in this instance and so on. This database is opened automatically when SQL Server starts.
So, when you want to connect to SQL Server, master database is already exist and cannot be attached. Information about this database you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187837.aspx)
I cannot understand why you need to attach this database. Maybe you don't need to attach this database, but only connect to it? If so, you need to change th code:

```
string strConnection2 = "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;initial catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;"
```